# Recursive "Fetch API" callback when all done

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My code:

```
function genTree(parent_id) {
    GetData('tableName', {
        'parent': parent_id
    }).then(function(features) {
        var feature = null
        for (var i = 0, total = features.length; i < total; i++) {
            feature = features[i]
            var temp = {}
            var parentIndex = getIndexById(parent_id);
            temp["ID"] = feature['ID']
            temp["PARENT_ID"] = feature['PARENT_ID'] || 0
            state.splice(parentIndex + (i + 1), 0, temp)
            genTree(feature['ID']);
        }
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log('Error', e)
    })
}
```

**getData()** is a function which using "Fetch API" and parse response xml to array. I'm not able to edit this function.

It works fine, but I have trouble with making callback with all data have been loaded. I'm looking for the best solution.

Answer (score 2):

If you return all the promises you create, and feed them to `Promise.all`, then your main function call will return a promise that will resolve when all has been resolved:

```
function genTree(parent_id) {
    return GetData('tableName', {
        parent: parent_id
    }).then(function(features) {
        var parentIndex = getIndexById(parent_id);
        return Promise.all(
            features.map(function (feature, i) {
                var temp = {
                    ID: feature.ID,
                    PARENT_ID: feature.PARENT_ID || 0
                };
                state.splice(parentIndex + (i + 1), 0, temp);
                return genTree(feature.ID);
            })
        );
    }).catch(function(e) {
        console.log('Error', e);
    })
}
```

Now you can do:

```
genTree(parent_id).then(function () {
    console.log('all done');
});
```

Note that I did not touch `state.splice(parentIndex + (i + 1), 0, temp);`, as it is not clear what `state` is, and how you use it, but I do wonder whether that is what you need, since `splice` will *move* existing array elements to the right when they are at greater indexes than the one given here. Consider doing instead:

```
state[parentIndex + i + 1] = temp;
```

Comment: "splice will move existing array elements to the right when they are at greater indexes than the one given here"
I want my state array have all items in order:
All childrens are on the right of (next to) parent. It was on purpose, but I'm not sure that is the best way to do this.

Comment: If it works for you then leave it as it is (it was not the subject of the question anyway). If it becomes an issue, I would suggest asking a new question about that specifically, but then you should also provide a sample of the data you process, in particular which the `feature.ID` are, and how you expect to find certain entries in `state` afterwards.

Comment: I have added .then(function () {} to my call of genTree() like:

genTree(mainProces_id).then(function () { });

And my error:

Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Comment: Did you add all the 3 `return` keywords where I put them?